# Iterate through a Namespace

Tags: python, namespaces

I have got a namespace looking like this :

> Namespace(aTQ=None, bE=None, bEQ=None, b=None, bQ=None, c=None,
>   c=None, cJ=None, d=None, g=None, jR=['xx', '015'], lC=None, l=None)

How can I iterate through it so I can find and replace the 'xx' value for the "jR" key in place ?

Comment: @martineau I thought I understood his question until I saw the blockquote; I thought he meant file namespace for packaging, but the blockquote seems to imply that he didn't mean that.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick: From the accepted answer, it's not what the OP meant, but something very similar was added to Python 3.3 `types` module called a [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) which its documentation says "may be useful as a replacement for `class NS: pass`".

Comment: what did you end up doing? Can you share your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not sure what you know in advance, (the name `jR`, or only that one name has a `not None` value) but you can try using `vars()` which, like `__dict__` should be a dict that has the names in your namespace as its keys.  So if you have the string `'jR'` somewhere,

```
vars()['jR'] = vars()['jR'][0]
```

likewise, you can get the same dict using `namespace.__dict__` instead of `vars()`

will leave you with the first value in `['xx','015']` as the only value for `jR`.

To be clear, since `vars()` and `__dict__` both return dicts, you can iterate through them as:

```
for k in namespace.__dict__:
    if namespace.__dict__[k] is not None:
        <<do something>>
```

Comment: does `vars` takes in `args` e.g. `vars(args)`? It seems from the question he clearly has an object with some type of `Namespace` structure/instance...can you address that?

Comment: @CharlieParker Not sure about other cases, but I was able to use `options.__dict__`, where `options` was a Namespace-structured result of calling the `argparse.parse_args` method -- so it seems you can use `__dict__` on arbitrary Namespace structures.