# How do I convert a list of parsed statements to a list or string that I can use in if statements?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parsing, image-recognition

I'm using the tutorial imagenet image identification code from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py

I have managed to get everything to work fine but I want to know how to get the arguments at the end as a list or string rather than parsed arguments so I can use normal if commands with them.

```
def main(_):
  maybe_download_and_extract()
  image = (FLAGS.image_file if FLAGS.image_file else
           os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir, 'cropped_panda.jpg'))
  run_inference_on_image(image)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  # classify_image_graph_def.pb:
  #   Binary representation of the GraphDef protocol buffer.
  # imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt:
  #   Map from synset ID to a human readable string.
  # imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt:
  #   Text representation of a protocol buffer mapping a label to synset ID.
  parser.add_argument(
      '--model_dir',
      type=str,
      default='/tmp/imagenet',
      help="""\
      Path to classify_image_graph_def.pb,
      imagenet_synset_to_human_label_map.txt, and
      imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt.\
      """
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--image_file',
      type=str,
      default='',
      help='Absolute path to image file.'
  )
  parser.add_argument(
      '--num_top_predictions',
      type=int,
      default=5,
      help='Display this many predictions.'
  )
  #how do i get a variable that i can interact with from this

  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

I have absolutely no experience with parsing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

Afetr the comment i looked at `ArgumentParser`. If you insert the method `parser.parse_args` you are returned a namespace. Now you can access its attributes, and you can get the values that the user passed.

```
#Every parameter can be accessed using namespace.parameter_name, for example
# with namepsace.model_dir, and you get the string inserted by the user

namespace = parser.parse_args()
if namespace.verbose:
    print("Verbose: ", + str(verbose))
```

If you want to iterate all the attributes you can use a dictionary like said in [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865961/iterate-through-a-namespace). Passing from dictionary to list is then easy.

---

### OLD ANSWER

For parsing input argument i use `getopt`. The hard part ot understand is how to specify the parameters and the optional parameters, but it's not to difficult.

`getopt` will return a list of arguments on which you can iterate and apply conditions. (see [getopt documentation for python 3.7.5](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/getopt.html), works also with python 3.6  and 2). I give you an example:

```
def main():
    options, remainder = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'tci:', ['train', 'classify', 'id'])
    for opt, arg in options:
        #This is a bool optional parameter
        if opt in ('-t', '--train'):
            train = True

        #This is a bool optional parameter
        elif opt in ('-c', '--classify'):
            predict = True

        #This is an integer required parameter
        elif opt in ('-i', '--id'):
            id= arg

    if train:
        funtion1()
    elif predict:
        function2(id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The documentation says:

> **getopt.getopt(args, shortopts, longopts=[])**
>   Parses command line options and parameter list. `args` is the argument list to be parsed, without the leading reference to the running program. Typically, this means `sys.argv[1:]`. **shortopts** is the string of option letters that the script wants to recognize, with options that **require an argument** followed by a colon (':'; i.e., the same format that Unix getopt() uses). **longopts**, if specified, must be a list of strings with the names of the long options which should be supported. The leading '--' characters should not be included in the option name. Long options which require an argument should be followed by an equal sign ('=').

Note that the user can put whatever he wants as a parameter and it's your concern to check if it's correct.

Comment: I'm sorry I barely even know how the original code works let alone how to change it. Can you give me more information? here is the code I'm using https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py

Comment: wait upon further inspection, this is not what I wanted. I understand this returns the parameters set by the user but i want to return the thing that the parser returns i.e. the prediction made by the imagenet. Your help would be very much appreciated - you seem like you know what you're doing.